# my code stopped functioning after changing variable names

Tags: javascript, html, variables

my code just hangs when I run it. It's a text based RPG. Right now all it is supposed to do is to be able to navigate a map(thats why there is a giant switch thing) and time passes. The problem I am having is that it just hangs on the starting screen after I changed the variable names(because before I used stupid ones like bacon and idiot).

```js
//topbar 
var game_time_display = document.getElementById("id_day_period");

//images
var image_map_display = document.getElementById("id_map_area_image");

//map navigation
var north = document.getElementById("id_north");
var east = document.getElementById("id_east");
var south = document.getElementById("id_south");
var west = document.getElementById("id_west");

//player's tile
var map_area_display = document.getElementById("test");

//gameplay variables
//player area
var map_area;
//time
var game_time;
var game_time_day;
var game_time_period;

//starting prefixes
map_area = 8;
game_time_part = 0;
game_time_day = 1;

//show player's tile
map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;

//1 game time part passing
function time_pass(){
game_time_part = game_time_part + 1;


//periods of the day: it is in this order for it to work
 if (game_time_part >= 50) {
 game_time_period = "EVENING";
}
else if (game_time_part >= 40) {
 game_time_period = "AFTERNOON";
}
else if (game_time_part >= 30) {
 game_time_period = "MIDDAY";
}
else if (game_time_part >= 20) {
 game_time_period = "MORNING";
}
else if (game_time_part >= 10) {
 game_time_period = "DAWN";
}
else if (game_time_part >= 0) {
 game_time_period = "EARLY MORNING";
}
else {}

//game day passing test
if (game_time_part > 60) {
 game_time_day = game_time_day + 1;
 game_time_part = 0;
}
//display on topbar
game_time_display.innerHTML = "DAY "+game_time_day+" "+game_time_period;
}
//normal travel on flat ground:3-5 game time parts?
function time_pass_flat_travel() {
time_pass()
time_pass()
time_pass()
time_pass()
}

function north_click() {
map_area = map_area - 1;
area.innerHTML = map_area;
map_navigation();
time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function east_click() {
map_area = map_area + 5;
area.innerHTML = map_area;
map_navigation();
time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function south_click() {
map_area = map_area + 1;
area.innerHTML = map_area;
map_navigation();
time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function west_click() {
map_area = map_area - 5;
area.innerHTML = map_area;
map_navigation();
time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function map_navigation(){
switch (map_area) {
  case 0:
        
        break;
  case 1:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map1.png";
   
        break;
  case 2:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map2.png";
        break;
  case 3:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map3.png";
        break;
  case 4:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map4.png";
        break;
  case 5:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map5.png";
        break;
  case 6:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map6.png";
        break;
  case 7:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map7.png";
        break;
  case 8:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map8.png";
        break;
  case 9:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map9.png";
        break;
  case 10:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map10.png";
        break;
  case 11:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map11.png";
        break;
  case 12:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map12.png";
        break;
  case 13:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map13.png";
        break;
  case 14:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map14.png";
        break;
  case 15:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map15.png";
        break;
  case 16:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map16.png";
        break;
  case 17:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map17.png";
        break;
  case 18:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map18.png";
        break;
  case 19:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map19.png";
        break;
  case 20:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map20.png";
        break;
  case 21:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map21.png";
        break;
  case 22:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map22.png";
        break;
  case 23:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map23.png";
        break;
  case 24:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map24.png";
        break;
  case 25:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "none";
   image_map_display.src = "map25.png";
        break;
  case 26:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map26.png";
        break;
  case 27:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map27.png";
        break;
  case 28:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map28.png";
        break;
  case 29:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map29.png";
        break;
  case 30:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "block";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map30.png";
        break;
  case 31:
   north.style.display = "none";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map31.png";
        break;
  case 32:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map32.png";
        break;
  case 33:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map33.png";
        break;
  case 34:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "block";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map34.png";
        break;
  case 35:
   north.style.display = "block";
   east.style.display = "none";
   south.style.display = "none";
   west.style.display = "block";
   image_map_display.src = "map35.png";
        break;
  }
  }
```

```html
<head>
<!--this shows the tile the player is on-->
<p id="test"></p>
</head>
<body>

<!--above the image; map area shows map area+local area-->
<div id="topbar">
<p id="id_health"></p>
<p id="id_map_area"></p>
<p id="id_pills_num"></p>
<p id="id_day_period"></p>
</div>

<!-- the image-->
<div id="parent">
<img id="id_map_area_image" src="map8.png">
</div>

<!--underneath the image-->
<div id="bottombar">
<p id="id_outfit"></p>
<p id="id_melee_weapon"></p>
<p id="id_ranged_weapon"></p>
</div>

<!--this is the overview of the map-->
<div id="map_menu">
<!--map navigation:-->
<p onclick="north_click()" id="id_north">GO NORTH</p>
<p onclick="east_click()" id="id_east">GO EAST</p>
<p onclick="south_click()" id="id_south">GO SOUTH</p>
<p onclick="west_click()" id="id_west">GO WEST</p>
<!--local navigation:-->
<p id="id_locale1"></p>
<p id="id_locale2"></p>
<p id="id_locale3"></p>
<p id="id_locale4"></p>
<!--random encounter:-->
<p id="id_map_loot_encounter"></p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Nope I did it on notepad

Comment: @JosephKwong R.I.P, at least get Sublime Text 3 or use JSFiddle for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JosephKwong look at `area.innerHTML = map_area;` in any of the `east_click()`, `north_click()`. The variable `area` is not defined. Either it's supposed to be `map_area.innerHTML = ...` or you need to define `area`.

Comment: `area` is supposed to be `map_area_display` @JosephKwong also create a HTML element with `id="test"`

Comment: @Alex thankyou very much it worked! I will be forever grateful.

Comment: No problem, select the best answer to not leave the question hanging.

Comment: A suggestion: Use a 2d array as the map so you can specify each coordinate. Then use something to signify the correct image. Eg: `var map = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]];` Then have an array with the images: `[ 'grass.jpg', 'player.jpg' ]`.
 Now write a render function that just creates the correct html from the map array, using the images array to get the correct image link. Moving now just becomes subtracting or adding one to the index of the player and then rerendering. Then you can completely remove the huge case statement and won't need to update it every time the map size changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have figured, you had an `undefined` variable `area`, if you look into the console, it throws a `ReferenceError: area is not defined`.

Also, create a HTML element with `id="test"`.

Here's my solution:

---

```js
//topbar 
var game_time_display = document.getElementById("id_day_period");

//images
var image_map_display = document.getElementById("id_map_area_image");

//map navigation
var north = document.getElementById("id_north");
var east = document.getElementById("id_east");
var south = document.getElementById("id_south");
var west = document.getElementById("id_west");

//player's tile
var map_area_display = document.getElementById("test");

//gameplay variables
//player area
var map_area;
//time
var game_time;
var game_time_day;
var game_time_period;

//starting prefixes
map_area = 8;
game_time_part = 0;
game_time_day = 1;

//show player's tile
map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;

//1 game time part passing
function time_pass() {
  game_time_part = game_time_part + 1;


  //periods of the day: it is in this order for it to work
  if (game_time_part >= 50) {
    game_time_period = "EVENING";
  } else if (game_time_part >= 40) {
    game_time_period = "AFTERNOON";
  } else if (game_time_part >= 30) {
    game_time_period = "MIDDAY";
  } else if (game_time_part >= 20) {
    game_time_period = "MORNING";
  } else if (game_time_part >= 10) {
    game_time_period = "DAWN";
  } else if (game_time_part >= 0) {
    game_time_period = "EARLY MORNING";
  } else {}

  //game day passing test
  if (game_time_part > 60) {
    game_time_day = game_time_day + 1;
    game_time_part = 0;
  }
  //display on topbar
  game_time_display.innerHTML = "DAY " + game_time_day + " " + game_time_period;
}
//normal travel on flat ground:3-5 game time parts?
function time_pass_flat_travel() {
  time_pass()
  time_pass()
  time_pass()
  time_pass()
}

function north_click() {
  map_area = map_area - 1;
  map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;
  map_navigation();
  time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function east_click() {
  map_area = map_area + 5;
  map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;
  map_navigation();
  time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function south_click() {
  map_area = map_area + 1;
  map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;
  map_navigation();
  time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function west_click() {
  map_area = map_area - 5;
  map_area_display.innerHTML = map_area;
  map_navigation();
  time_pass_flat_travel()
}

function map_navigation() {
  switch (map_area) {
    case 0:

      break;
    case 1:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map1.png";

      break;
    case 2:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map2.png";
      break;
    case 3:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map3.png";
      break;
    case 4:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map4.png";
      break;
    case 5:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map5.png";
      break;
    case 6:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map6.png";
      break;
    case 7:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map7.png";
      break;
    case 8:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map8.png";
      break;
    case 9:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map9.png";
      break;
    case 10:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map10.png";
      break;
    case 11:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map11.png";
      break;
    case 12:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map12.png";
      break;
    case 13:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map13.png";
      break;
    case 14:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map14.png";
      break;
    case 15:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map15.png";
      break;
    case 16:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map16.png";
      break;
    case 17:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map17.png";
      break;
    case 18:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map18.png";
      break;
    case 19:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map19.png";
      break;
    case 20:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map20.png";
      break;
    case 21:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map21.png";
      break;
    case 22:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map22.png";
      break;
    case 23:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map23.png";
      break;
    case 24:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map24.png";
      break;
    case 25:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "none";
      image_map_display.src = "map25.png";
      break;
    case 26:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map26.png";
      break;
    case 27:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map27.png";
      break;
    case 28:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map28.png";
      break;
    case 29:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map29.png";
      break;
    case 30:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "block";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map30.png";
      break;
    case 31:
      north.style.display = "none";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map31.png";
      break;
    case 32:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map32.png";
      break;
    case 33:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map33.png";
      break;
    case 34:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "block";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map34.png";
      break;
    case 35:
      north.style.display = "block";
      east.style.display = "none";
      south.style.display = "none";
      west.style.display = "block";
      image_map_display.src = "map35.png";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<div id="topbar">
  <p id="id_health"></p>
  <p id="id_map_area"></p>
  <p id="id_pills_num"></p>
  <p id="id_day_period"></p>
</div>

<!-- the image-->
<div id="parent">
  <img id="id_map_area_image" src="map8.png">
</div>

<!--underneath the image-->
<div id="bottombar">
  <p id="id_outfit"></p>
  <p id="id_melee_weapon"></p>
  <p id="id_ranged_weapon"></p>
</div>

<!--this is the overview of the map-->
<div id="map_menu">
  <!--map navigation:-->
  <p onclick="north_click()" id="id_north">GO NORTH</p>
  <p onclick="east_click()" id="id_east">GO EAST</p>
  <p onclick="south_click()" id="id_south">GO SOUTH</p>
  <p onclick="west_click()" id="id_west">GO WEST</p>
  <!--local navigation:-->
  <p id="id_locale1"></p>
  <p id="id_locale2"></p>
  <p id="id_locale3"></p>
  <p id="id_locale4"></p>
  <!--random encounter:-->
  <p id="id_map_loot_encounter"></p>
</div>
```